# SSL/TLS support in AWS ELB/NLB with multiple instance ports assigned to Load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

AWS NLB does not allow SSL but ELB does. 
However NLB supports adding multiple instance ports to LB where as ELB does not.

Is there way to support multiple ports for LB with SSL transport?

For instance I have 4 services running on 2 nodes.

- Node1 hosts service1_master (port 1111) and service2_slave (port 1112)
- Node1 hosts service2_master (port 1111) and service1_slave (port 1112)

Service1 and Service2 are running in Active/Passive mode. Meaning only one port, either 1111 or 1112 can be active for each service.

I would like to add port 1111 and 1112 to the listener over SSL/TLS.
Is that possible with AWS load balancers.

Comment: AWS Network load balancer support TLS now https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/ As Tim mentioned, if you could post more details of your problem we can help solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Network load balancer works at at a fairly low network level - it can pass through any TCP traffic. It doesn't terminate SSL / HTTPS like ELB / ALB, but it can load balance just about anything. It supports multiple ports.

If you can edit your post to give more detail about what you're trying to achieve, rather than just describing the problems you have, you will probably get more useful help.